# Calculating the correlation matrix

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I am trying to calculate the correlation matrix of the results of SVD using the following Python code. However the result is a single large number. I am also not sure whether this code should produce the same result as `pd.DataFrame(vh).corr()` or `pd.DataFrame(vh).corr(method ='kendall')`
Please see the following images for clarification of what I am trying to do:

[image: Sigma v transposed]

[image: normalised columns]

This is the python code that I am trying to use:

```
u, s, vh = svd(A, full_matrices=False)

sigma_vh = s.dot(vh)

e_normed = sigma_vh / sigma_vh.max(axis=0)

eh = np.transpose(e_normed)

ehe = eh.dot(e_normed)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Given the initial matrix, using your code gives a matrix. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. Btw, dividing by the maximum does not make a vector of length 1. You need to divide by its norm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should divide `sigma_vh` by the norm of each column in order to normalize columns, namely:

```
e_normed = sigma_vh / np.linalg.norm(sigma_vh, axis=0)
```

Other than that I see no issue.

Comment: Will the above code do the same as: import pandas as pd pd.DataFrame(vh).corr()